# I want to refresh div content into 'chat.php' without blinking. I have database query in data

Tags: php, ajax

This is database section and this query helps to display data on `chat.php`. I almost tried but messages are not loaded? why it is?

```
<meta name="mymeta" http-equiv="refresh" content="15" id="loading"/>

</script>
<?php
    session_start();
     if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
         $id=$_SESSION['id'];
     }

     include 'dbconnection.php';
     $_SESSION['lawyer']=$_GET['id'];
     $id1=$_SESSION['lawyer'];
     $sql="SELECT * from chat WHERE from_user_id=$id && to_user_id=$id1 or from_user_id=$id1 && to_user_id=$id ORDER by chat_date";

     $result=$conn->query($sql);



        if ($result->num_rows>0) {



        while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
           echo'<---display data--->';

   <?php
```

Comment: Inline PHP is not AJAX style. On your client side, use JavaScript (or jQuery) codes to make an AJAX call to a PHP page that returns the data like your database page. Then on the client side, put the received data into whichever HTML element you want.

Comment: Are you sure "&&" is the correct SQL syntax for your database?  Usually it's "AND".

Comment: Use separate files for backend and frontend

Comment: This query has an SQL injection vulnerability in it.